# Obtain proxy for a newly added entity in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

I'm in the process of early research to replace EF with NHibernate in a system that is implemented using a custom written app engine.

The client creates an entity say, Person, gets the property values from the user and sends it to the server. In the server, we used `context.CreateObject<Person>()` to obtain a proxy of a Person.
Then the property values where applied to the proxy and we were able to Use Lazy loading to access related objects. For instance, if the person had a property `MajorID` and a navigation property `Major`, we set `MajorID` to `5` and if an expression accesses `Major`, the correct `Major` is lazily loaded into this field. A similar process happens for updates.

In NHibernate, I don't have a `CreateOject<>()` method, so the object I have is not proxied, and therefore lacks Lazy-Loading. Also, in Update, if I Change MajorID and then access Major, it still points to the old, wrong Major.

I'm quite new to NHibernate, can I have it behave like EF in this scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `CreateObject` at all in NHibernate.

The implementation of proxies in NH is completely different from EF, and it's based on entities, not properties.

Here's how this would work in NH:

```
var person = new Person(); //no proxy needed; person is a new entity
person.Major = session.Load<Major>(majorId); //creates Major proxy, no DB call
//...somewhere else
var majorId = person.Major.Id; //getting the Id does not cause loading, ever
var foo = person.Major.Foo; //this causes lazy-loading if not already loaded.
```

An interesting thing to note is that there is no `MajorId` property, nor there is need for one, because unlike EF, you can create proxies for already persisted entities.

Comment: Well, I'd already thought about setting the navigation property, in the server, from the foreign key property (I totally need the fk property, I've used it in many automatic wire-ups in the client).
What I did not notice was the fact that setting the major from its ID will not cause a database hit. So, I'd ruled out this solution because of unnecessary queries... Thanks for pointing in the right direction.\

Comment: And now you also know why I dislike EF: because it forces you to think in relational terms (foreign keys vs navigation)

Comment: Making preassumptions about how developers are going to solve a problem is the most common problem with API design. Some of these assumptions are essential, as you need to decide to drop some features, in order to support others excellently. But, when you face no important trade-off, it is better to allow the developer to decide, otherwise, you're unnecessarily limit the architectures in which your system can perform. I use the foreign-keys in an excellent way in the client, that minimizes network usage, ui delay, and complexity. Losing FKs, I lose my architecture!!

Comment: Sometimes you can think of FKs + their property type as a unique locator for what you can show the user, as opposed to a relationship in a relational world.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve wat you use by `session.Get<>` and passing the ID of the person you want to load. For the id part, you generally should not works with it directly when you maniulate associations. Why dont you just try something like:

```
var p = session.Get<Person>(personId);
p.Major = session.Get<Majors>(mayorId);
session.Update(p);
```

Comment: In insert scenario, the Person is just created. I need to run several queries to validate it, some of which may pass through navigation properties.

Comment: Yeah, I know the point: in an OO world, foreign-keys are replaced by navigations. But, in our architecture, the foreign-key properties play a major role and I'll need to make major changes to eliminate this requirement.